# How to use zgrep and regular expression?

Tags: regex, linux, zcat, zgrep

I'm trying to do some research in a `.gz` file so I found out I should use `zcat / zgrep` now after a bit of research I can't figure out how to use a regex with `zgrep`

I tried to do it like this `zgrep '[\s\S]{10,}' a.gz` but nothing comes out even if there are string of minimum 10 characters in the file.

So how could I use `zgrep` to display string of minimum 10 characters ?

Comment: You should not use `\S` and `\s` in a POSIX BRE regex bracket expression. Use `.` instead of `[\s\S]`. Also, in a BRE pattern, `{10,}` looks like `\{10,\}`. So, try `zgrep '.\{10,\}' a.gz`

Comment: even with `zgrep '.{10,}' a.gz` nothing comes out

Comment: `{10,}` won't work as it matches ``{10,}`` string.

Comment: so how should I do it then ?

Comment: See my top comment: *So, try `zgrep '.\{10,\}' a.gz`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `\S` and `\s` in a POSIX BRE regex bracket expression as `[\S\s]` bracket expression matches either `\`, `S` or `s`.  Use `.` instead of `[\s\S]` to match any char with a POSIX BRE/ERE regex.

Also, in a BRE pattern, `{10,}` must be written as `\{10,\}` as otherwise, when unescaped, `{10,}` matches a literal `{10,}` string.

Use

```
zgrep '.\{10,\}' a.gz
```